# I have a problem on my Flutterproject, I can't build, this is the error I have:

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

  > Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
  >   The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.3.0,16.3.0], [16.5.0,16.5.0]], but resolves to 16.5.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
  >   The library com.google.firebase:firebase-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[17.0.4,17.0.4]], but resolves to 19.0.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

These errors do not give much info but I would try these:

1. run `flutter doctor`
2. make sure you have properly implemented Firebase (it looks like you use it in your project)
3. open the project's Android folder with Android Studio and if it prompts you, install the missing dependencies. You might encounter gradle problems that VS Code does not find but Android Studio can fix.

Hope it helps.